# Add custom layout to ActionBar/Toolbar with no margins

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-toolbar

I want to create a custom height toolbar and it works fine until I add content to it. Then my content is adjusted to be between the back arrow and the actionbar buttons.

How can I make my content take the entire width so I can create a layout like below? I guess the "+" icon needs to be in a parent layout of the toolbar?

The docs say:

> The application may add arbitrary child views to the Toolbar. They will appear at this position within the layout. If a child view's Toolbar.LayoutParams indicates a Gravity value of CENTER_HORIZONTAL the view will attempt to center within the available space remaining in the Toolbar after all other elements have been measured.

But I don't have the gravity set to CENTER_HORIZONTAL...
[image: Layout I want]

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:iosched="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        iosched:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay"

        iosched:popupTheme="@style/ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
        android:background="@color/theme_primary"
        iosched:titleTextAppearance="@style/ActionBar.TitleText"
        iosched:contentInsetStart="16dp"
        iosched:contentInsetEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="128dp" >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        ... My Content
```

Currently my layout ends up like this when running with left margin set to 168:

[image]
[image: layout]

Comment: I'm not sure in the case above they used a custom actionbar, seems like they attached a view below and that's it.

Comment: Actually that's my own Photoshop drawing so that's real :-) I need to make the title move up into the toolbar when scrolling so to accomplish that I'd rather have it as part of the toolbar layout if possible...

Comment: I think i understand what you need but it's not necessary to have the view inside the actionbar. Otherwise you can create your own actionbar

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'm not sure if you still need help with this, but it has the most votes for an unanswered question in not only the [android-5.0-lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-5.0-lollipop) tag, but also the [android-toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-toolbar) tag right now. So, I thought I'd give it one.

This layout is pretty easy to achieve, especially with the new [Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html).

**Implementation**

The root of your hierarchy will need to be the [`CoordinatorLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html).

**As per the docs:**

> Children of a CoordinatorLayout may have an anchor. This view id must
>   correspond to an arbitrary descendant of the CoordinatorLayout, but it
>   may not be the anchored child itself or a descendant of the anchored
>   child. This can be used to place floating views relative to other
>   arbitrary content panes.

So, we'll use this to position the [`FloatingActionButton`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html) where it needs to go.

The rest is pretty straightforward. We're going to use a vertical `LinearLayout` to position the `Toolbar`, text container, tab container, and then a `ViewPager`. So, the full layout looks like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#181E80"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@android:id/icon"
                android:layout_width="54dp"
                android:layout_height="54dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:importantForAccessibility="no"
                android:src="@drawable/logo" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@android:id/text1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@android:id/icon"
                android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@android:id/icon"
                android:text="Chelsea"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignStart="@android:id/text1"
                android:layout_below="@android:id/text1"
                android:text="England - Premier League"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:background="#272F93">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:tabContentStart="70dp"
                app:tabGravity="center"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="#F1514A"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabTextColor="#99ffffff" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_star_white_24dp"
        app:backgroundTint="#F1514A"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="8dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/tab_container"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

There's not a whole lot more to add, the only other thing I'd mention is how to use the [`TabLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html). If you're using a `ViewPager` like we are, you'd probably call one of the two:

- [`TabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setTabsFromPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter))
- [`TabLayout.setupWithViewPager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setupWithViewPager(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager))

**Notes**

I just kind of eyeballed the dimensions, trying to match the picture as much as possible.

**Results**

[image: results]