# Get title textview of collapsing toolbar layout

Tags: android, textview, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a `collapsingToolbarLayout` and I need to do some additional setup to the title `TextView`.

**Question:** How can I get a reference to that TextView ?

[image]

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/review_coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.stack.overflow.reviewmaschine.ReviewMaschineActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/detail_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/item_detail_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior = "@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

    <com.mego.smscloud.reviewmaschine.SaveFloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/review_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_floppy_white_48dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="@dimen/fab_elevation"
        app:rippleColor="#00ffff"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Edit:** 
Simply adding a `TextView` to the `Toolbar` does not integrate it in the same behavior as `CollapsingToolbarLayout` title does
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Toolbar` class creates its child `View`s as needed, so that `TextView` won't exist until you've set the title on the `Toolbar`. After you've done that, there are a couple of options.

You could iterate over the `Toolbar`'s child `View`s - using the `ViewGroup#getChildCount()` and `getChildAt()` methods - looking for a `TextView`. If there are no other `TextView`s in the `Toolbar`, then the title will be the only one. If there are others, you should check the text against what you set as the title.

Another option is to use reflection to grab the title `TextView` field. For example:

```
private TextView getTitleTextView(Toolbar toolbar) {
    try {
        Class<?> toolbarClass = Toolbar.class;
        Field titleTextViewField = toolbarClass.getDeclaredField("mTitleTextView");
        titleTextViewField.setAccessible(true);
        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) titleTextViewField.get(toolbar);

        return titleTextView;
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

You should, of course, do a null check before doing anything with this method's return.

Comment: I have checked your answer as solution because it returns the right textview for me. Unfortunately I cannot set anything to the textview. Please see my code:    protected void onResume() {
        mTitleTextView = (TextView) getTitleTextView(mToolbar);

        if(mTitleTextView != null){
            mTitleTextView.setText("BLJSDosdjif");
        }

        super.onResume();
    }

Comment: Well, the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is going to be setting things on the `Toolbar`, like the title. That code might work if you move it after the `super.onResume()` call. I'll have a look at the source code for `CollapsingToolbarLayout` later when I get a chance, but I've not used it much yet, so I'm not sure exactly how it handles things, atm.

Comment: I have tried to run the code after super.onResume(). Unfortunately it still does not work. I would be very grateful if you have a little look at it. Thank you in advance

Comment: Well, I've got some bad news. You should un-accept my answer, because it's not currently correct. I was wrong about the interaction between `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and `Toolbar`. The `Toolbar`'s title `TextView` is not what you're seeing in the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. The Layout hides the `Toolbar`'s title, and draws it itself. The title there is not a `TextView`. It's drawn directly to the Layout's `Canvas` by an internal helper class. We still _might_ be able to do what you're trying, but it'll take a lot more reflection, and you'll have to be specific about what you're trying to change

Answer (score 0):

This is the default title of the `Toolbar` If you would like to change the title, then just call:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(String title);
```

But that just changes the text.

However, if you would like to do more modifications append your own `TextView` to the `Toolbar`. Like that:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/detail_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <TextView
          android:id="@+id/title"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And then just find the title in you `Activity`

```
TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately the expected behavior of a collapsable title textview is not given. Please see my edited post

Comment: Maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26861843/add-custom-layout-to-actionbar-toolbar-with-no-margins) will help you to add gravity to elements.